# How do you handle stale data with multiple threads?

Tags: sql, multithreading, postgresql, transactions, locks

Let's say I have the following psuedocode:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = 'bob@gmail.com'
>>>> MARKER A
if (count > 0) return;
else INSERT INTO users VALUES ('bob@gmail.com')
```

So essentially only insert the email if it doesn't exist already. I understand there's probably some sort of INSERT IF NOT EXISTS query I could use, but let's say we use this example.

So if the code above runs on thread A, and thread B actually inserts 'bob@gmail.com' into users at MARKER A, then thread A has "stale data" and will try to insert 'bob@gmail.com', thinking the count is still 0, but in fact it is now 1. This will error out since we have a unique index on the email.

**What is the tool I should use to prevent this issue?** From my reading about transactions, they basically make a set of operations atomic, so the code above will execute completely or not at all. It will NOT ensure the users table is locked against updates correct? So I can't just wrap the code above in a transaction and make it thread-safe?

Should I implement application-level locking? Should I ensure that when this operation occurs, it must acquire the lock to access the users table so that no other thread can make changes to it? I feel that locking the entire table is a performance hit I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Checking before inserting is a known anti-pattern on multi-threaded applications. Do not even try it.

The right way of doing it is letting the database take care of it. Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column, as in:

```
alter table users add constraint uq1 unique(email);
```

Just try to insert the row in the database. If it succeeds, all is good; if it fails, then some other thread has alreay inserted the row.

Alternatively, you could issue a LOCK on the whole table. That would also work, but the performance of your application would become horrible.

Comment: +1. Adding a `UNIQUE` constraint also allows you using [UPSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT): `INSERT INTO users VALUES ('bob@gmail.com') ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uq1 DO NOTHING;`